# IntelliJ shortcut ctr + / adds a comment at the first column instead of current

Tags: java, intellij-idea, comments, keyboard-shortcuts

When I want to comment or comment my code out with the shortcut `ctrl` + `/`, IntelliJ puts the `//` at the first column instead of the current. How can I make comments at the current?

Example

```
        System.out.println(set.containsAll(subSet));
```

```
//        System.out.println(set.containsAll(subSet));
```

Using `ctrl` + `/`, I would like to make it like that

```
        //System.out.println(set.containsAll(subSet));
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- Settings | Editor | Code Style | Java | Code Generation | Comment Code | Line comment at first column -> Uncheck
- Settings | Editor | Code Style | Java | Code Generation | Comment Code | Block comment at first column -> Uncheck
- Settings | Editor | Code Style | Java | Wrapping and Braces | Keep when reformatting | Comment at first column -> Uncheck